# Wierd format of Modified date and PublishingStart

Tags: xslt, xml, date-time

Iam having trouble with date formats of these two fields: Modified and PublishingStartDate. They are different in format. Iam attaching how they display on my computer. I have regional settings set to dutch (1043).

```
PublishingStartDate="13-7-2012 0:00:00"
Modified="2012-12-14 07:38:59"
```

The main problem raises when we are sorting list items based on these two fields, can you give me some advice how to get the right format of these two dates with using f.e.

```
ddwrt:FormatDateTime()
```

function?